# react how to unselect on second click and not on third

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, react-hooks

Learning React by coding, here i have different cameras, these cameras get active when button is clicked like button 1 (camera 1), button 2 (camera 2), when i click one of those buttons then starts filtering which then shows filtered version in < graph>,  i have graph where my filteredGraphData affects, when button is clicked it filters, but then when same button is clicked second time it should unfilter or unselect but it does not, it only does it for some reason when i click same button third time. Any idea why it unfilters/unselects it in third click and not in second click ?
I have been stuck with this for few hours now

```js
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";


  const intialState = {
   extendDetails: false,
 };
  const visualGraph = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.graph.graph
 );
 const currentCam = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.currentCam 
);
  const [filteredGraphData, setFilteredGraphData] = useState<any>("");
  const [toggleSiteCheckmark, setToggleSiteCheckmark] = useState(intialState);

useEffect(() => {
    if (currentCam ) {
      const filterCamera = () => {
        let nodes = nodes.filter(
          (x: any) => x.camera == currentCam.identifier
        );

        let links = links.filter((x: any) =>
          nodes?.map((y: any) => y.id).includes(x.source)
        );

        let sourceNodess = nodes.filter((x: any) =>
          links.map((y: any) => y.target).includes(x.id)
        );

        let allNodes = nodes?.concat(sourceNodess);
        setFilteredGraphData(
          toggleSiteCheckmark.extendDetails == false
            ? { links: links, nodes: allNodes }
            : visualGraph
        );

        setToggleSiteCheckmark({
          ...toggleSiteCheckmark,
          extendDetails: !toggleSiteCheckmark.extendDetails,
        });
      };
       filterCamera();
    }
  }, [currentCam]);
  
  console.log("filteredgraphdata", toggleSiteCheckmark.extendDetails);

  
   <Graph 
          data={ toggleSiteCheckmark.extendDetails
          ? filteredGraphData
          : visualGraph}
        />
```

Enlish is not my mother language, could be mistakes.

Comment: any help is appreciated !

Comment: Its because your filter states are updated inside the useEffect, which only runs when `currentCam` changes. Is there missing code in your example? Can we see the checkboxes and how they set the state when clicked?

Comment: Also just one important thing, when setting state derived based on previous state (like toggling) you must use the version of the state set function that accepts a callback, that is passed the prev state `setToggleSiteCheckmark(oldState => { ...oldState , extendDetails: !oldState.extendDetails, });` Not doing so can lead to stale values, which may or may not be your issue.

Comment: I see. Try first changing the state setters to the form above which takes a closure that is passed the previous state

Comment: @AdamThomas the one which you gave, it gives me this error : A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Comment: Oops minor mistake: `setToggleSiteCheckmark(oldState => ({ ...oldState , extendDetails: !oldState.extendDetails, }));`

Comment: @AdamThomas same problem with this one also

Comment: Damn :(. Leave it that way though, as this is the desired form. Could it be to do with something around there being no null handling of `currentCam` in the effect? Im assuming, when they unselect the cam, that this is then `null` or `undefined` . When this occurs, you need to check for it and reset the filters. At the moment, nothing happens because `filterCamera` only runs when `currentCam` is truthy (not  null). I think this is the problem.

Comment: @AdamThomas when i refresh the page and first time click the button, it filters, but then after that i need to click two times to unfilter and again two times to filter. So in the beginning filtering works in first click but after that unfilter and filter works only after second click

Comment: This could still explain that though. You are missing null handling in the effect. This also explains why it works on third try. First the camera is set; then second camera is unset but the `if` prevents any of the state updates from running since its null; and then on the third click the camera is set and state updates run again.

Comment: @AdamThomas could you possibly give some null handling so i can try, i have been battling this for few days now

Comment: Its really hard without more context (like a codesandbox) so I can see it happening. But I will do an answer now on my best attempt. Give me 10 min

Comment: cool, ive added a possible solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because you need to reset the filters back to their original state when `currentCam` is null/falsey. See the else block.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentCam ) {
      const filterCamera = () => {
        let nodes = nodes.filter(
          (x: any) => x.camera == currentCam.identifier
        );

        let links = links.filter((x: any) =>
          nodes?.map((y: any) => y.id).includes(x.source)
        );

        let sourceNodess = nodes.filter((x: any) =>
          links.map((y: any) => y.target).includes(x.id)
        );

        let allNodes = nodes?.concat(sourceNodess);
        setFilteredGraphData(
          toggleSiteCheckmark.extendDetails == false
            ? { links: links, nodes: allNodes }
            : visualGraph
        );

        setToggleSiteCheckmark((oldState) => ({
          ...oldState,
          extendDetails: !oldState.extendDetails,
        }));
      };
       filterCamera();
    } else {
       setToggleSiteCheckmark(intialState)
       setFilteredGraphData("")
    }
  }, [currentCam]);
```

What is happening is that now when the user unselects the cam, the effect run, but this time time `currentCam` is null. This means it goes into the else block and the state items are set back to their initial values. This means the logic on the next try works properly as everything is reset.

Comment: should i still use this which u gave: setToggleSiteCheckmark(oldState => ({ ...oldState , extendDetails: !oldState.extendDetails, })); ?

Comment: Yes, thats preferable when the new state value is based on the old one

Comment: Nice one! Yeh so basically -- to explain my answer a bit more -- what is happening is that now when the user unselects the cam, the effect run, but this time time `currentCam` is null. This means it goes into the `else` block and the state items are set back to their initial values. This means the logic on the next try works properly as everything is reset.

Comment: could you add this your comment to answer, it would help others

Comment: Cool yep, done 

Comment: could you possibly also answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158201/react-broken-state-from-drawimage